# Web forms routing and keywords in route url

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

I am having routing weirdness. Are certain keywords a problem in route paths. For example, this route works:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("AdminLogin", "horse", "~/AdminAccount/Login.aspx");
```

But this route to the same resource fails:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("AdminLogin", "admin", "~/AdminAccount/Login.aspx");
```

It does a login redirect to the root loginform designated in the web.config file and the whole site locks up.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. There was a folder in the project directory called Admin. It was defaulting to that folder, which is behind security.